# How to make max-width text and jump to next line

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I'm facing a tiny problem. I'm not able to solve it.
I'm using the awesome Ionic framework to build a nice application. trying to work with list items.
I'm setting a max width for the text, and I want test to jump to the next line, this is not working, I'm using `word-wrap: break-word;`

my text is appearing like that :

[image]

I want the text to jump next line.

Here is : [CODEPEN CODE + DEMO](http://codepen.io/stranger90/pen/vOXJYx)

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything, really. If you set max-width on your h3 tag it should break by default in multiple lines like so: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPVmdr

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to overwrite the default ionic CSS from white-space: no-wrap

```
.item h3 {
  white-space: normal !important;
}
```

[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqbmXM)

**Output**

[image: Normal wrap]

But I would try to use a custom CSS file and load it after ionic CSS to avoid using !important

Answer (score 5):

Overwrite the white-space property for line-break, and to center the text add margin-left and margin-right auto;

```
a.item h3 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/usmanarshad87/pen/KpNmLN)